# gradle dependency report does not show jar fie

Tags: android, performance, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I added a jar file to my project successfully: 
compile files('libs/poi-3.9.jar')
I was even able to use the api.
I went to the root directory of my project, then from the command line I ran:
gradlew app:dependencies

when I looked over the report, there is no mention of poi-3.9.jar

If I understand this correctly, this report is suppose to show all my dependencies. 
I tried to run it with the following extention: --configuration compile
still didnt work. How can I get a complete list of my dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

From the gradle docs:

> File dependencies are not included in the published dependency
>   descriptor for your project.

I don't think it's possible to get what you are looking for with standard gradle commands at this time.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:file_dependencies

Answer (score 0):

If you are building android app ,Please try this. You can confirm jar dependencies!

```
./gradlew androidDependencies
```

Example

```
release
+--- LOCAL: disklrucache-2.0.2.jar
+--- LOCAL: basic-http-client-android-0.88.jar
+--- LOCAL: YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar
+--- LOCAL: volley.jar
+--- LOCAL: gcm.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.0.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.1.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:7.0.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.1.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.0.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.1.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.0.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.1.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.0.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.0.1.jar
...
```